# Drupal multisite setup

Tags: drupal-6

I am trying to setup drupal to host multiple sites which will not effect each other. My pages are hosted on a shared hosting service and I only have access to cPanel. 
Following the instructions on the web that I found using google, I have done the following.

1. Installed Drupal.
2. Make a directory in sites and name it demo.sharedhost.com.
3. Copied default.settings.php in that directory and renamed it settings.php.
4. Created a subdomain demo.
5. Deleted the demo folder from public_html
6. Made sybolic link public_html/demo to sites/demo.myshost.com.

When I try to access demo.myhost.com I get listing of sites/demo.myhost.com directory instead of drupal installation.

Can you please help me setup multisites?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. In 6th step I made a symbolic link to drupal_installation/sites/demo.myhost.com, these instructions are wrong on the internet. The sybolic link should be targeted to drupal_installation path.

So here is my final steps:

1. Installed Drupal in **~/public_html/drupal_path**.
2. Make a directory in **~/public_html/drupal_path/sites** and name it **demo.myhost.com**.
3. Copied **default.settings.php** in  **~/public_html/drupal_path/sites/demo.myhost.com** directory and renamed it **settings.php**.
4. Created a subdomain demo.myhost.com.
5. Deleted the demo folder from public_html, which was created automatically.
6. Made sybolic link as follow:
   **ln -s ~/public_html/drupal_path ~/public_html/demo**
   Note: If you do not have access to shell then use the following php script to make the symlink:

   ```
   <?php
         exec("ln -s ~/public_html/drupal_path/ ~/public_html/demo"); 
   ?>
   ```
7. Finally visit the demo site by http://demo.myhost.com and you will be prompted for new drupal installation.

I am explaining the steps again so someone like me will not have to waste time reading different solutions posted on the internet.

Please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Instead you can copy settings.php already existing and change db name in it

Comment: step 3 mentioned the copying of setting.php file and I can change the db setting but I prefer a fresh install and let drupal take care of modifying settings.php

Comment: you used the command line to create the symbolic link? i'm new to Drupal and I'm trying to figure out how to create multi-sites. i'm trying to learn how to create a symbolic link.

Comment: create a simple php script and use symlink(drupal_installation_path, subdomain_target_path). Please try the code on a local server for testing and then try it on your host.

Answer (score 0):

[Multi Site in Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/290768)
You need to make sure first if the server supports virtual hosts or not ,
You have not created the database for sites , follow that link for this,
If all went well till now to install another site you shouldnt access

```
demo.myhost.com
instead try this
demo.myhost.com/install.php
```

Comment: There is no install.php present in site/demo.myhost.com folder and even if I copy the install.php from the main drupal folder it doesn't work.

Comment: Dont copy to the site folder just go to demo.myhost.com/install.php , why wont you gie a try and post any errors after this

Comment: As I mentioned that I went to demo.myhost.com/install.php and I get 404 not found error. Anyway the solution to the problem was symbolic link, which I mentioned in the answer below and the site is working.